# How to fix problems between Jmeter and the software

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm new in here and I have a lot of doubts about jmeter. How to know the problems between Jmeter and the software when I run a test and then the results it's not that clear. For example the 100% Error, can someone help me a little bit please.

Answer (score 0):

Open the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode) in a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), it normally contains [HTTP Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and HTTP Status Message or other error message like connection timeout, connection reset, etc. Looking into it you should be able to figure out what's wrong.

It is also possible to [save full request/response data for the JMeter samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter), you can do this either by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

once done on next run of your test you will be able to see what's going on under the hood. Alternative option is i.e. using [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener, example configuration:

[image]

Comment: The Response Code: 302   /   Reply message: Found  /   HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text / html; charset = UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Comment: I saw that the connection was canceled, I'm completely lost with JMeter test, thanks anyway, I will figure it out